# Infinite loop in Pascal, how come?

Tags: loops, inno-setup, freepascal

I wrote a Pascal function to replace either a whole line, or just a part of it, in a file, for use in Inno Setup:

```
function ReplaceInFile(const FilePath, OldLinePart, Replacement: String;
                       DoReplaceWholeLine, IsCaseSensitive: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  FileLines:          TArrayOfString;
  Index:              Integer;
  FoundAtPos:         Integer;
  LeftOfOldLinePart:  String;
  RightOfOldLinePart: String;
  IsReplaced:         Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if FileExists(FilePath) then begin
    LoadStringsFromFile(FilePath, FileLines);
    for Index := 0 to GetArrayLength(FileLines) - 1 do
    begin
      repeat
        FoundAtPos := 0;
        if IsCaseSensitive then
          FoundAtPos := Pos(OldLinePart, FileLines[Index])
        else
          FoundAtPos := Pos(Uppercase(OldLinePart), Uppercase(FileLines[Index]));
        if FoundAtPos > 0 then begin
          if DoReplaceWholeLine then begin
            FileLines[Index] := Replacement;
            IsReplaced := True;
          end
          else begin
            LeftOfOldLinePart := Copy(FileLines[Index], 1, FoundAtPos - 1);
            RightOfOldLinePart := Copy(FileLines[Index], FoundAtPos 
              + Length(OldLinePart), Length(FileLines[Index]) 
              - Length(LeftOfOldLinePart + OldLinePart));
            FileLines[Index] := LeftOfOldLinePart + Replacement + RightOfOldLinePart;
            IsReplaced := True;
          end;
        end;
      until FoundAtPos = 0;
    end;
    if IsReplaced then
      if SaveStringsToFile(FilePath, FileLines, False) then
        Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

It used to work just fine, but replaced only the first occurrence of the OldLinePart on each line of the file specified by FilePath, with the Replacement. That is when I added the repeat loop. The logic is that `Pos()` returns 0 when no more occurrences are found. Then it should go on to the next line. The truth is however, that the loop keeps going infinitely and I have no idea why. I tried adding a `Break` statement in the `else` clause of `if FoundAtPos > 0`, but no luck...

**Edit:** Obviously it is getting late. I was replacing the OldLinePart with a very long string... that contained the same word.

The issue has been resolved as follows.

```
function ReplaceInFile(const FilePath, OldLinePart, Replacement: String; DoReplaceWholeLine, IsCaseSensitive: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  FileLines: TArrayOfString;
  Index: Integer;
  SearchLinePart: String;
  FoundAtPosition: Integer;
  SearchOffset: Integer;
  LeftOfOldLinePart: String;
  RightOfOldLinePart: String;
  IsReplaced: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if FileExists(FilePath) then
  begin
    LoadStringsFromFile(FilePath, FileLines);
    for Index := 0 to GetArrayLength(FileLines) - 1 do
    begin
      SearchOffset := 0;
      SearchLinePart := FileLines[Index];
      repeat
        FoundAtPosition := 0;
        if IsCaseSensitive then
          FoundAtPosition := SearchOffset + Pos(OldLinePart, SearchLinePart)
        else
          FoundAtPosition := SearchOffset + Pos(Uppercase(OldLinePart), Uppercase(SearchLinePart));
        if FoundAtPosition > SearchOffset then
        begin
          if DoReplaceWholeLine then
          begin
            FileLines[Index] := Replacement;
            IsReplaced := True;
            Break;
          end
          else
          begin
            LeftOfOldLinePart := '';
            RightOfOldLinePart := '';
            LeftOfOldLinePart := Copy(FileLines[Index], 1, FoundAtPosition - 1);
            RightOfOldLinePart := Copy(FileLines[Index], FoundAtPosition + Length(OldLinePart), Length(FileLines[Index]) - Length(LeftOfOldLinePart + OldLinePart));
            FileLines[Index] := LeftOfOldLinePart + Replacement + RightOfOldLinePart;
            IsReplaced := True;
            SearchOffset := Length(LeftOfOldLinePart + Replacement);
            SearchLinePart := RightOfOldLinePart;
          end;
        end;
      until FoundAtPosition <= SearchOffset;
    end;
    if IsReplaced then
      if SaveStringsToFile(FilePath, FileLines, False) then
        Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Here's a possibility: You are using a test case where the value is always found. Thus (perhaps) your function Pos() returns a value and this modifies the variable FoundAtPosition. So the loop never ends. Againk, this is only if you are testing with values that are always found.

Comment: @itsols: Well, what I want to have replaced in the file, happens to be in the filename as well. But it would be silly if `Pos()` parsed that. A couple of other search terms I now tried, seem to work though...

Answer (score 2):

I Replaced your loop with a single call to [StringReplace](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=StringReplace). This prevents the (infinite) loop and solves the problem.
Note that you also had a problem with `IsReplaced`, if e.g. `FileLines[4]` was replaced, but not `FilesLine[last]` then your code would not call `SaveStringsToFile`.
It also simplifies the code somewhat.

```
uses SysUtils;

function ReplaceInFile(const FilePath, OldLinePart, Replacement: String;
                       DoReplaceWholeLine, IsCaseSensitive: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  FileLines:          TArrayOfString;
  Index:              Integer;
  TempStr:            String;
  IsReplaced:         Boolean;
  Flags:              TReplaceFlags;
  IsReplacedAnywhere: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if FileExists(FilePath) then begin
    LoadStringsFromFile(FilePath, FileLines);
    IsReplacedAnywhere:= false;
    for Index := 0 to GetArrayLength(FileLines) - 1 do begin
      if DoReplaceWholeLine then begin
        IsReplaced := 
          IsCaseSensitive and (Pos(OldLinePart, FileLines[Index]) > 0) or 
          not(IsCaseSensitive) and 
           (Pos(Uppercase(OldLinePart), Uppercase(FileLines[Index])) > 0);
        if IsReplaced then FileLines[Index] := Replacement;
      end
      else begin
        Flags:= [rfReplaceAll];
        if not(IsCaseSensitive) then Flags:= Flags + [rfIgnoreCase];
        TempStr:= StringReplace(FileLines[Index], OldLinePart, Replacement
                                ,Flags);
        IsReplaced := (TempStr <> FileLines[Index]);
        if IsReplaced then FileLines[Index]:= TempStr;
      end; {else}
      IsReplacedAnywhere:= IsReplacedAnywhere or IsReplaced;
    end; {for Index}
    Result:= IsReplacedAnywhere 
             and SaveStringsToFile(FilePath, FileLines, False);
  end; {if}
end;
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: There is no possibility to use the full power of Delphi, since Inno Setup only supports some subset of Pascal. Inno does have a string replace function, but I would not know how to make that one case insensitive. What you are saying about IsReplaced is not the case, by the way. Once IsReplaced is set to True, the save function will be called, because IsReplaced is never set to False.

Comment: @thoiz_vd, `after:= stringreplace(Upper(before), Upper(StrFrom), StrTo);`

Comment: @thoiz_vd, about `IsReplaced`, I see. But in my code you need to leave the `IsReplacedAnywhere`, because the `IsReplaced` does double duty to see if replacement is necessary.

Comment: I could not use `StringChangeEx()` in Inno Setup, because I would need to feed it my whole string capitalized, which would result in the output string being capitalized as well. I just modified my own function to only search the parts that have not been searched yet.

Answer (score 0):

This should now be done with StringChangeEx.  It is nice that it supports Unicode.  It is not nice the way he breaks old scripts by removing old functions.  StringReplace doesn't compile anymore; even though it is the Delphi function for doing this.  StringChange is already deprecated.

Comment: Inno Setup's scripting is based on Pascal Script and has published only functions wanted by authors. They could have name those functions totally different or assign them different meaning from Delphi. Delphi and Pascal are something different from custom scripting language based on Pascal Script.

Comment: I understand that Inno Pascal is not Delphi, nor did I claim that it was.  My comment was an answer as to how to do it, and a complaint about obsoleting old code without sound reason.  I mentioned Delphi only because it being the Delphi function, it might be more widely known; as well as obsoleting old code.  You haven't demonstrated that my answer is wrong.